# How can I get an image to always appear to the right of some associated text using HTML and/or CSS?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2010

I've got this HTML:

```
<div>This page provides a brief overview of the travel process, as well as many of the resources that travelers need. For guidance on best travel practices, see <a href="bla.com" target="_blank">Key Tips for UCSC Travelers</a>, which was designed to provide tips of preparing, booking, and reimbursement of travel expenses.<span><img class="ucsc_image_dynamic_size" alt="Access Connexxus Booking Tool" src="/PublishingImages/access_connexxus.gif"/></span></div>
```

I want the text to appear to the left side of the image (not above it); how can I accomplish that with HTML and/or CSS?

As is, it looks like this:

[image]

### UPDATE

In answer to the question in the comment, here is the class the image uses:

```
.ucsc_image_dynamic_size {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Is the image width always fixed?

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: I think if you are going to have that image always be just to the right of that particular text, regardless of what text is added before, then you will have to use some JavaScript. As far as I know, there is no way using CSS to set the position of one object based on the position of another object.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Ya JavaScript could be the easy way, but using HTML/CSS it's little hard to think. I am not saying it isn't possible but i am not that aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you just need to put the image's HTML first, then float it right?

```
<div>
    <img class="ucsc_image_dynamic_size" alt="Access Connexxus Booking Tool" src="/PublishingImages/access_connexxus.gif"/>
    This page provides a brief overview of the travel process, as well as many of the 
    resources that travelers need. For guidance on best travel practices, see 
    <a href="bla.com" target="_blank">Key Tips for UCSC Travelers</a>, 
    which was designed to provide tips of preparing, booking, and reimbursement of travel expenses.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ucsc_image_dynamic_size {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 1em;
}
```

Or am I missing something?
Example JSFiddle (with placeholder image): http://jsfiddle.net/4s8evpod/1/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for layout.

```
<style>
  .outer {
    display: flex;
  }   
</style>

<div class='outer'>
  <div>    
    This page provides....
  </div>
  <div>
    <img>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/budq0s0u/)